# How to change this variable declaration base on if statement to switch case

Tags: c#

I have the following code in "_sharedView.cshtml":

```
var modelStuff = controller == "A" ? Model.AStuffs : Model.BStuffs;
@foreach (var c in modelComment)
{
    <span>@c.Content</span>
}
```

A model

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual List<AStuff> AStuffs { get; set; }
}
```

AStuff model

```
public class AStuff
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

A controller

```
return PartialView("_sharedView",model);
```

Bstuff is basically the same as Astuff (Model, Controller).

How to change the code above to switch case?

**Update:**
Model is different base on what model pass to view.

**Update:**
Add more detail.

Comment: What's `modellStuff`'s type? Does it implement the `IEnumerable` interface?

Comment: Yes, it does implement IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Change `var` to `IEnumerable` and make sure your `AStuff`, `BStuff` etc. implement this interface.

```
IEnumerable modelStuff = null;
switch (controller)
{
    case "A":
        modelStuff = Model.AStuff;
        break;
    case "B":
        modelStuff = Model.BStuff;
        break;
    default:
        // do stuff what should be done here
}

if (modelStuff != null)
    foreach (var s in modelStuff)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it show the following error "implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized". I want to change to switch case because there will be more case: CStuff, DStuff,....

Comment: you cannot use var to define modelStuff without an assignment it needs to be defined as a Model presumeably and set to a default value

Comment: Change `var` to `IEnumerable` and make sure your AStuff, BStuff etc. implement this interface.

Comment: I changed it, but it show the following error : "local variable may not have been initialized" in the foreach line.

Comment: See update. You may not have implemented all cases properly. I added a `null` scenario and proper variable declaration.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... After i add a `null` scenario like your update, i can't access modelStuff value inside foreach loop.
    `foreach (var s in modelStuff)
    {
        s.someValue // error "Cannot resolve symbol 'someValue'"
    }`

Comment: You haven't shared the loop code before. BTW, this is a new question though easiest is to cast `s` into whatever you need. Make sure it's of a type which has the values you're looking for.

Comment: I can't think of anyway i can cast `s` easily... I have add more detail to the question.

Comment: You need a base class (e. g. `ModelBase`) that holds the `Content` property. `AStuff`, `BStuff` etc. need to inherit.  Your loop need to change to `@foreach (ModelBase c in modelComment)`. As I said, it's a different question, please post it as a new question and close this one as your original problem has been solved.